# If in mysql I have string `xxx yyy` - how can I SELECT this if user input `xxxyyy`?

Tags: mysql, select, like

My online-shop in PHP (OpenCart). On site we have product-search. For example product have name `iSport 220`, and if user search input string is `iSport220` we must show this product. And vice versa.

First my thought was about `LIKE` operator, but I see that I need something different. In list of [MySQL string functions](http://www.w3resource.com/slides/mysql-string-functions.php) I do not find any useful. What the best practice for this kind of problem? Version of MySQL is 5.5.

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you are asking?  Where does 'xxx yyy' come from? What is it? It might be useful to state what version of MySQL are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the better solution: on php-level surround user's input by `%` and remove spaces:

Regex search for numbers:

`preg_match('/\d+/', $search, $matches);`

Replace substring with numbers to substring with numbers surrounded by %:

`$search = str_replace($matches[0], '%'. $matches[0] . '%', $search);`

Remove spaces:

`$search = str_replace(' ', '', $search);`

Answer (score 1):

Replace space and compare:
`... where replace('xxx yyy',' ','') = 'xxxyyy'`

or generally it can be: `... where replace(column,' ','') = 'xxxyyy'`

But not that this may not like your indexes on the columns.

Comment: What about if in db I have `xxx yyy` and user input is `xxxyyy` without spaces?

Comment: That's why we are replacing space in column.

Answer (score 0):

You can `REPLACE` the spaces in `xxx yyy` and `xxxyyy`, so when you make a search it will look for `xxxyyy`:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM test.tbl1
WHERE REPLACE(tbl1.searchfield,' ','') = REPLACE('xxxyyy');
```